# Should this be moved to math.stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-topic, math-stackexchange

I posted [Lower bound on Carmichael Function](https://mathoverflow.net/q/343659)

and just assumed it belonged here, but after thinking about it for some time I'm not so sure. The Carmichael function itself might be encountered by other enthusiasts, so it could be nice to have this on the math.se site, but this question particularly asks for the state of the art and any references known so it felt fitting for the research half of the math community.

Comment: If it's of interest to research mathematicians, it has a home here. This is a public site; there's no reason enthusiasts wouldn't browse MO as well as MSE.